# Initializing generic Collection

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, collections, cannot-find-symbol

It has been a few years since programming in Java, so I decided to consult an old, reliable source. In "Introduction to Java Programming" by Liang, pg. 798, an `ArrayList` is scheduled like so:

```
Collection<String> collection = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The author then goes about using (only) the `add()` method and creates an uses an `Iterator` of `collection`.

Now, I like using a generic class declaration whenever possible (coming from, now, a C and C++ background) because if I change my mind about the type I want to use for some solution, I can change just one line of code. Ideally, I would be able to declare a `Collection<some_type> my_collection` (whether a member or local variable), and later define it to be any type which extends the `Collection` class.

But, when I try to do the following,

```
Collection<String> my_collection;
```

and then later,

```
my_collection = ArrayList<String>();
```

I get compilation errors: namely, the compiler cannot find the `get()` and `remove()` symbols (or at least not the versions of the overloaded methods that I *believe* I am calling). For example,

```
[...].java:48: error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to Process
        otherAlg.addJob(wait_queue.remove(0));
                                         ^
```

NOTE: the type Process is "fully-vetted" and is not the issue here.

Also,

```
[...].java:72: error: cannot find symbol
        return wait_queue.get(0);
                         ^
```

Sure: I can "fix" the issue by declaring whatever type I am going to initialize in the first place, but what is the deal? Why the inconsistency between what Liang states and what I would assume to be possible, and what is actually practical (at least as far as my compiler is concerned)?

Comment: What is the return type of `remove(int)`? What does this have to do with the original `Collection<String>`? What is `wait_queue`? Your question is all over the place at the moment. Please clarify and provide a [MCVE].

Comment: The compile-time type of my_collection is [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), which has neither a get method nor a remove(int) method.  The fact that you initialized it to an ArrayList is irrelevant;  the type of the variable is remembered only as a Collection, as far as the compiler is concerned.  When in doubt, read the official documentation;  in Java, the docs are not just for assistance, they are law.

Comment: `my_collection = ArrayList<String>;` should be `my_collection = new ArrayList<String>();`.

Comment: @shmosel Right: fixed that.

Comment: @WatermarkBranding no you didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the rest of your program is aware your `wait_queue` is just a `Collection`, it doesn't have `get` or `remove` methods.

You're correct in that you don't want to couple your implementation to the variable's type, however you shouldn't use `Collection` unless you only want to iterate over the contents. Use `List`, `Set`, or other collections interfaces to describe collections. These expose the `get` and `remove` (in the case of the `List`) methods you want, and expose the **behaviour** of the object (but not the implementation - in this case `ArrayList`). e.g., a `List` allows duplicates whereas a `Set` does not.

Comment: Collection actually does have remove methods

Comment: @ControlAltDel Right: just not the overloaded ones I'm expecting which belong to `ArrayList`.

Comment: Okay I see that now. Thanks for the answer.